# Panda - how to produce several csv files registering group's data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe with the following information :

| Country | Region | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | Pas de Calais | 500000 |
| France | Provence | 200000 |
| Switzerland | Geneva | 400000 |
| United States | Florida | 1200000 |

Could you please indicate to me how I can process to get one CSV-file per country, with all data for that country ?

Many thanks in advance for your guideline

Comment: provide a script to generate the dataframe please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby("Country").apply(lambda df_country: df_country.to_csv(df_country.Country[0]+".csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

My recomendation is:

```
data = {'Country': ['France', 'France', 'Switzerland', 'United States'], 'Region': ['Pas de Calais', 'Provence', 'Geneva', ' Florida'], 'Population': [500000, 200000, 400000, 1200000]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


grouped_df = df.groupby(by = 'Country')

for _, subdf in grouped_df.__iter__():
  
    # save subdataframe
    subdf.to_csv()
```